# ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied

Tags: git, gitosis

Gitosis config:

```
[gitosis]
loglevel = DEBUG

[group gitosis-admin]
writable = gitosis-admin
members = root.server

[group testgroup]
writable = testproj1
members = Anastasia@ANASTASIA-PC
```

My log, when I call clone command:

```
myuser@mydomain /d/www
$ git clone git@5.9.30.109:repositories/testproj1
Cloning into 'testproj1'...
DEBUG:gitosis.serve.main:Got command "git-upload-pack 'repositories/testproj1'"
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Access check for 'myuser@mydomain' as 'wr
itable' on 'repositories/testproj1'...
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'myuser@mydomain' in 'testgroup'
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Access check for 'myuser@mydomain' as 'wr
iteable' on 'repositories/testproj1'...
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'myuser@mydomain' in 'testgroup'
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Access check for 'myuser@mydomain' as 're
adonly' on 'repositories/testproj1'...
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'myuser@mydomain' in 'testgroup'
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Whyyyy? :(

How can I issue this.

I already changed the rights for post-update.

Comment: Why gitosis through? it has been obsolete for *years* now. The new one is called gitolite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309

Answer (score 0):

This error is `usuallly` seen when the ssh key for `myuser` hasn't be properly added to the `keydir` folder of the `gitosis-admin` repo:

- incorrect format
- multiple lines instead of one
- or the public key added in the keydir folder isn't properly named '`myuser.pub`' (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6145662/6309))

The other can be linked to a `gitosis.conf` format issue (as [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435776/gitosis-error-receiving-read-access-denied-on-previously-accessible-repositor#comment3681019_3465769))

Either way, gitolite is easier to maintain and more up-to-date than gitosis (see "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)").

Comment: Did not understand what the problem is. Solution: Install gitolite.

Comment: I already tried these solutions, even before you have given the answer. Thank you.